# tortoisegit: how to upload entire project?

Tags: tortoisegit

How do I upload an entire Visual Studio project(200 files) into GIT?
I don't want to have to do one file at a time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is, I start a repository in the working dir that I wanted to ad (Git -> Init from the context menu).

I go to 'Git -> Diff' (make sure 'Show unversioned files' and 'Show whole tree' are ticked).

I select all the files to be added at once (multiselect using ctrl-click or shift-click for contiguous region)). Right-click to add. The files are now displayed in the top part of the screen.

I usually take the effort to *ignore* or *delete* the remaining files. When you choose to ignore a file, you get the option to ignore the specific path or all files with the same extension. **Click refresh button to see the effect of new ignores**.

**Hint**

> Sometimes it is more practical to do some ignores up front in order to trim the list of unversioned files shown (make sure that 'Show ignored files' is _un_ticked). For Visual Studio projects, `*.pdb`, `bin/`, `obj/`, 'Debug/' etc. come to mind.

Finally, click the commit button, and you're done (enter message and click ok).

#### Alternative:

If you have many projects like this to add, you'd drop into a shell (like git-bash):

```
cat >> .gitignore <<HERE
*.user
*.suo
_Resharper*
Debug
Release
*scc
# be creative
HERE

git init .
git add .
git commit -am 'initial import'
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

Right click in Windows Explorer -> Git create repository here

Right click in Windows Explorer -> Git commit

Enter commit message

Check all files (there is a button for this)

Click OK to commit

Click Push

Click Manage remote

Add a remote: give a name and URL

Click OK to back to Push Dialog

Click OK to push